# Excel - Calculate average of 90% of the lowest value

Tags: excel

I have 1000 values and I want to calculate the average for 900 of the lowest value.
So it's finding the 900 lowest value and calculate the average of this values
Tks
Arnaud

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this array formula:

```
=AVERAGE(SMALL(A1:A1000,ROW($1:$900)))
```

just enter formula in formula bar and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to evaluate it